# "Implicit conversion loses integer precision" while getting random numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, arc4random

My plan was to get the random members of the array, therefore, I tried the solution which, firstly, generate the random number:

```
NSUInteger rnd = arc4random_uniform([myArray count]);
```

However, I got the warning "Implicit conversion loses integer precision".

How too work around that warning? Is there another way to get the random value which won't cause any warnings? I prefer only code implementations, not through the settings as several answers to the similar questions suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code to the following :

```
NSUInteger rnd = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) [myArray count]);
```

The compiler gave the warning as on your machine, NSUInteger is a typedef of 64 bits, which may not be the case for other devices. Therefore, casting it, removes the warning.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. I almost found the same answer myself (https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/how-can-i-avoid-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-warning-following-treehouse-steps) but you were the first. Perhaps it would be different suggestions.

Comment: I hope you're not getting the warning now.